# Treeview - Unable to restore previous selection on clicking cancel on a message pop up that is placed on a NodeMouseClick event

Tags: c#, .net, treeview

Consider a TreeView control containing multiple nodes. On selecting a node, certain information is displayed on a text box. This information can be modified and saved. Accidentally, if a user navigates to a different node without saving, a pop is displayed asking the user to save or cancel the action. If cancel is clicked, selection should remain on the previously selected node instead of a new node. The logic to display pop up is written in NodeMouseClick() event of TreeView. Is there any way to achieve this ?. Below is the sample code snippet.

```
private void TreeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, 
TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Cancel 
    Clicked......!!!","Information", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, 
    MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    if(dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
            //Need to handle previous node selection
    }
}
```

NodeMouseClick() event doesn't seem to be providing any information to cancel the event. I have already tried BeforeSelect() event of TreeView to cancel the event using below code snippet.

```
 private void TreeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
 {
        e.Cancel = true;
 }
```

But the above code removes the selection on all the nodes and doesn't suffice the need. Is there any way we can retain previous selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this in the `TreeView`'s `BeforeSelect` event.

If you added an event handler for the `BeforeSelect` event that literally just does `e.Cancel = true` you will never be able to select a node as the selection will be canceled every time. Instead, you need to show your message box inside of the `BeforeSelect` event, and set `e.Cancel` based on the result of the message box.

```csharp
private void treeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
   if (DataIsDirty())
   {
      if (MessageBox.Show(
            "Unsaved changes detected. Press OK to switch nodes and lose the change, or Cancel to stay on the current node.",
            "Unsaved Changes Detected",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.Cancel)
      {
          e.Cancel = true;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick suggestion Joshua Robinson. It did work with this changes.